# Scripture for $E^p(G)$

Tags: group-theory

I use the notation in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focal_subgroup_theorem for $O^p(G), A^p(G), E^p(G)$. We also denote $G^p:=\langle g^p:g\in G\rangle$.
Note that $G^p\le E^p(G)$.
I know that:

1. $A^p(G)=G'O^p(G)$.
2. $O^p(G)\subseteq A^p(G)\subseteq E^p(G)$.
3. $E^p(G)=G$ (i.e. $G$ has nonormal subgroups of index $p$) iff $G=G'G^p$ [Th.5.4 in https://scholar.rose-hulman.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1012&context=rhumj].

I ask if in general $E^p(G)=G'G^p$?  If $O^p(G)\le G^p$?

How can i generalize point 3 with a connession between $E^p(G)$ and $G'G^p$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $O^p(G)$ is generated by all $p'$-elements of $G$, and they are all trivially in $G^p$, $O^p(G)\leq G^p$. For the other claim, certainly $G'\leq E^p(G)$, and since $G/E^p(G)$ has exponent $p$, $G^p\leq E^p(G)$. Thus $G'G^p\leq E^p(G)$. It suffices therefore to check that $G/G'G^p$ is elementary abelian, but it is abelian of exponent $p$, so we are done.